# Return all locations, users, and roles where a user has 'X' role in each location (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am needing to write a query to identify all locations, users, and roles from a table where a user has 'X' role in each location.

The table has three columns (A = location, b = user, c = role).

A is a varchar, b is an INT, and c is an INT. Suppose the table contains the following:

```
A                 B           C
location 1        1           1
location 1        1           2
location 2        1           1
location 1        2           1
location 1        2           2
location 3        2           1
```

I am wanting to return all locations (A), users (B), and roles (C) where the location (A) and user (B) contains roleID 2 in C.

The expected result from the above table is:

```
A                B            C
location 1       1            1
location 1       1            2
location 1       2            1
location 1       2            2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "where the location and user contains roleID 2" - your expected result seems to simply be location 1 data?

Comment: `select * from table1 where A = 'location 1'` is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable t1 
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 
   FROM YourTable t2 
   WHERE t1.A = t2.A 
      and t1.B = t2.B 
      and t2.C = 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called "relational division". The only problem is that your textual description contradicts with your desired output. For the output provided, the wording should be "get all data for locations where all users are members of the role 2", which is quite different. Anyway:

```
declare @t table (
    LocationId varchar(20) not null,
    UserId int not null,
    RoleId int not null
);

insert into @t values
('location 1',1, 1),
('location 1',1, 2),
('location 2',1, 1),
('location 1',2, 1),
('location 1',2, 2),
('location 3',2, 1);

-- What you have said
select t.*
from @t t
    inner join (
        select c.LocationId, c.UserId
        from @t c
        where c.RoleId = 2
        group by c.LocationId, c.UserId
        having count(*) = (select count(distinct cn.LocationId) from @t cn)
    ) sq on sq.UserId = t.UserId and sq.LocationId = t.LocationId;

-- What you seem to need
select *
from @t r
where exists (
    select t.LocationId
    from @t t
    where t.LocationId = r.LocationId
    group by t.LocationId
    having count(distinct t.UserId) = count(distinct case t.RoleId when 2 then t.UserId end)
);
```

(I can't operate in terms like A, B, C - it hobbles my mind. So above is a proper table.)